# GCP PubSub mysteriously/silently failing with Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have about a dozen or so GCF functions (Python) which run in series, once a day. In order to keep the correct sequence, I use PubSub. So for example:

topic1 triggers function1 -> function1 runs -> function1 writes a message to topic2 -> topic2 triggers function2 -> function2 runs -> etc.

This use case is low throughput and a very straightforward (I thought) way to use GCF and PubSub together to each others advantage. The functions use `pubsub_v1` in Python to publish messages. There are no problems with IAM, permissions, etc. Code looks like:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# Publish message 
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic2 = publisher.topic_path('my-project-name', 'topic2_id')
publish_message = '{short json message to be published}'
print('sending message ' + publish_message)
publisher.publish(topic2, publish_message.encode("utf-8"))
```

And I deploy function1 and other functions using:

```
gcloud functions deploy function1 --entry-point=my_python_function --runtime=python37 \
--trigger-topic=topic1 --memory=4096MB --region=us-central1 \
--source="url://source-repository-with-my-code"
```

However, recently I have started to see some really weird behaviour. Basically, function1 runs, the logs look great, message has seemingly been published to topic2...then nothing. function2 doesn't begin execution or show anything in the logs to suggest it's been triggered. No logs suggesting either success or failure. So essentially it seems that either:

- the message from function1 to topic2 is not getting published, despite function1 finishing with `Function execution took 24425 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`
- the message from function1 to topic2 is getting published, but topic2 is not triggering function2.

Is this expected behaviour for PubSub? These failures seem completely random. I went months with everything working very reliably, and now suddenly I have no idea whether the messages are going to be delivered or not. It also seems really difficult to track the lifespan of these PubSub messages to see where exactly they're going missing. I've read in the docs about dead letter topics etc, but I don't really understand how to set up something that makes it easy to track.

1. Is it normal for very low frequency, short messages to "fail" to be delivered?
2. Is there something I'm missing or something I should be doing, e.g. in the `publisher.publish()` call to ensure more reliable delivery?
3. Is there a transparent way to see what's going on and see where these messages are going missing? Setting up a new subscription which I can view in the console and see which messages are being delivered and which are failing, something like that?
4. If I need 100% (or close to that) reliability, should I be ditching GCF and PubSub? What's better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you aren't waiting for `publisher.publish` to actually succeed. This method returns a future and may not complete synchronously. If you want to ensure the publish has completed successfully, you need to call `result()` on the value returned from `publish`:

```
future = publisher.publish(topic2, publish_message.encode("utf-8"))
future.result()
```

You will also want to ensure that you have "Retry on failure" enabled on your cloud function by passing the `--retry` argument to `gcloud functions deploy`. That way, if the publish fails, the message from topic1 will be redelivered to the cloud function to be tried again.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Is there any reason why I could have been having no issues at all with my non-rigorous method for many months (no .result() call) and then suddenly it was failing almost every other day? Just a quirk?

Comment: Yeah, this can depend on what happens to the Cloud Functions instances once the code finishes running. When there is outstanding async work, it may run at a much lower priority. As a result, the requests could timeout. This could depend on a lot of external factors and could really happen at any time. We have seen it be fine for people for a very long time and then have problems, sometimes only temporarily. Using `result()` will ensure this type of thing doesn't happen.